# Send data from view to controller, then to another view

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to send a variable to a controller, and then use this variable in another View.

View1.html
var cat = 5;

Controller.js
//get that cat=5 variable

View2.html
//get that cat=5 too, from Controller

View2.html has to check if var cat=5 has changed from View1.html in order to change some links inside View2.html

Tried using ng-init but can't put a variale inside its value, the value I'm trying to pass is a variable I get from an UrlParameter.

Also tried using a Publish-subscribe channel. But both views are loaded at the same time, and View2.html tries to get the value from View1.html before it's set.

Also tried using $scope and ng-model, using a hidden input field, but apparently, it only gets values as I type, so, if I assign a value directly it is not saved.

This is what i have right now:

view1.html

```
$('.listaPromociones').append
    ('<input type="hidden" ng-model="newCategory" value="'+cat+'"/>{{newCategory}}...
```

JS

```
 $scope.categoryId= $scope.newCategory;
```

view2.html

```
var link = 'http://localhost/principal.html?cat={{categoryId}}';
```

If you need more parts of the code let me know:

http://embed.plnkr.co/Gfwh4SKnJSnyl59jTw3j/

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same controller in both views? If yes, you can reference the variable in view 2, but this don't is a good practice, you should create another controller bounded with view 2 and you can share this value between both them using a service or via parameters, if I understand your issue, this is my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

1.- dont mix angular with jquery to manipulate the DOM this is not the angular way and can cause conflicts, bugs and problems

2.- dont mix script and link tags everywhere its not a good practice

now to fix your problem you can do two things: either you create a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) that persists your value and [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for value changes to customize the behavior you want or you bind this variable to the rootscope and also watch this value to fire a callback on change...